# imacro iframe extract and match every id with 'name'

Tags: javascript, iframe, imacros

i need to extract the frame name (not number) from html source, and then check every 'name' on the page for match. this is my macro:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET frame EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/name="(\w*)"/)[1];")
PROMPT {{frame}}
FRAME NAME={{frame}}
```

the extract get only the first 'name' on the html source:
    meta name="viewport"

i want to extract the 'name' from the end:
scrolling="no" name="w20awv3sfky5"
or every 'name' on the html source.

or, if there is option to extract the 'name' that close to scrolling its be good, but this macro not working:
    SET frame EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/scrolling="no" /name="(\w*)"/)[1];")

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try in the following way:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IFRAME ATTR=SCROLLING:NO EXTRACT=HTM
SET frame EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/name="(\w+)"/)[1];")
PROMPT {{frame}}
FRAME NAME={{frame}}
```